# null, message from server: "Host 'myserver' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am developing an Stand alone application in java, where i am using MYSQL as Database. My code is working fine on my system. I am using Ubuntu Operating system.

When i am trying to Run same code on different system it gives me above Error.

Comment: It is very normal for a MySQL database to only respond to request from the same machine

Answer (score 4):

you need to grant permission in Mysql

```js
use the_database_name;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 
the_database_name.* 
TO 
'the_user_name'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 
'password_of_the_user';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your myserver is not in the network of the second system.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) access permissions to the different server.  Set up a user id and password along with its machine IP address.